# Using BigCommerce as a Headless service with Nextjs from the frontend, and Nestjs for the backend

Tags: next.js, nestjs, bigcommerce, headless

I am new in the BC world, and docs are a little bit confusing to me.

I want to use BC API-s with Nextjs and Nestjs.

Basically, I want to create a classic web app, on the server, it will be Nestj which will communicate with BC API-s directly, and storefront Nextjs which will communicate with my custom API-s endpoints from the Nest js server.

I am not sure is possible, and if it is, I don't understand do I need a custom database such as MongoDB, Postgres, or any other, or BC give some Cloud options to store data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a database at all. BigCommerce as an ecommerce service is the record holder for Customers, Products, Orders, ... everything you need to build a generic e-commerce store.